# after submitting edit form getting null value, when i am checking console

Tags: angular

**I am using Form Builder and form group.
Once i am submit the form i am getting null value. Please tell me where is the problem.
Below is my code.**

**My object is:**

```
[ { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "city": "chennai", "street": "sivan koiil street", "pin": "600024" } ]


    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onMy()"><div *ngFor="let data of myarray; let i = index">{{data | json}}
<div class="form-group"><label for="firstname">First Name</label><input type="text" value="{{data.firstname}}"  class="form-control" name="firstname" formControlName="firstname"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="lastname">Last Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" formControlName="lastname"></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="city">City</label><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="city" formControlName="city" ></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="street">Street</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" formControlName="street" ></div>
<div class="form-group"><label for="pincode">Pin Code</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="pincode" formControlName="pincode"></div></div
><div class="form-group"><button type="submit">Submit</button></div></form>
```

**and my .ts file code is given below**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormGroup, FormControl,FormBuilder,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
animations: [routerTransition()]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
myForm: FormGroup;
myarray=[];
constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {
this.myarray=[{"firstname":"ramu","lastname":"mothukuri","city":"chennai","street":"sivan koiil street","pin":"600024"}];
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
firstname: [],
lastname: [],
city:[],
street: [],
pincode: []
});
}
onMy(){
console.log(this.myForm.value);
}
ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

**For reference i am edited first name, but after submitting i am getting empty object in console.**

out put is :

> {firstname: null, lastname: null, city: null, street: null, pincode:
>   null}

Please find attached screen
[image: screen shot form],
    [image: console image]

Comment: @ccjmne, kindly tell me the where is the problem

Comment: Don't upload pictures of text. The problem is in your `onMy` function, you're not referencing your `data` object's relevant properties properly.

Comment: Sure, I have used below code in my onMy Function : onMy(){ console.log(this.myForm.value);
} . Please tell me where is the problem

Comment: post your component code, (*.ts) file

Comment: @Timothy i have updated my .ts code in my question section, please check and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we are dealing with an array, so what you need is a `FormArray` (here I have named it `users`). Second, you need to set your values to the form controls, `value` is useless in this case. So your build of form should look like this:

```ts
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  users: this.fb.array([])
})
```

Then you want to iterate your array and set each object as a `FormGroup` to your array:

```ts
let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
this.myArray.forEach(user => {
  formArr.push(this.fb.group({
    firstname: user.firstname
    // rest of form controls
  }))
})
```

Then in your template you need to iterate your `FormArray` and mark each formgroup with the index value:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onMy()">
  <ng-container formArrayName="users">
    <div *ngFor="let user of myForm.controls.users.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="firstname">
      <!-- more fields here -->
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-67owqj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

If you know that you have only one user in the array, you can skip the formarray altogether and just extract the data from the first (and only) object in your array...

```ts
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  firstname: [this.myArray[0].firstname]
  ...
})
```

and template would simply then look like:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onMy()">
  <input formControlName="firstname" />
  <!-- more fields here -->
</form>
```

Comment: Excellent problem is solved. I need the output formate like :  { "firstname": "ramu" ,"lastname":"mothukuri" },  can you help me AJT

Comment: Glad to hear, as for your followup question... Then you go with the second option I wrote in answer, if you know you only have one object, just forget the formarray and extract the data from array: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xndgpj?file=app/app.component.ts :)

Comment: I got Thanks AJT, I think multiple objects we will use form array other wise we will normal formgroup right.

Comment: I need small clarification. I am getting response from service and i am displaying. but you mention "myArray = [ { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "city": "chennai", "street": "sivan koiil street", "pin": "600024" } ]".  how to do that one