# Angular 2. How to use formArray in reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, kendo-ui-angular2

I've got a problem with reactive forms in kendo angular grid.
My model(book) has a collection of authors, which I want to display in my grid column. But I didn't find any information how to work with collection in reactive forms. So my template doesn't display data correctly.

**This is my Authors collection in formGroup:**

```
this.formGroup = createFormGroup({
  genre: {
    genreId: 0,
    genreName: ''
  },
  'bookName': '',
  'pages': 0,
  'publisher': '',
  //here
  authors: new Array<Author>()
});
```

How should I declare authors in formGroup?Did I do that right?

**My html template:**

```
<kendo-grid-column field="authors" title="Authors" width="250">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <div *ngIf="dataItem.authors">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let author of dataItem.authors">
            <strong>{{author.authorsName }}</strong>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

As I wrote at the beginning, template doesn't work correctly. If you have any questions, I will be glad to answer you.
I am hope for your help.

**UPD:**
I changed my FormGroup

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  'genre': {
    genreId: 0,
    genreName: ''
  },
  'bookName': '',
  'pages': 0,
  'publisher': '',
  authors: this.fb.array([{
    authorId: [''],
    authorName: [''],
  }]),
  //authors: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

**FormControls initializing:**

```
const createFormGroup = dataItem => new FormGroup({
  'bookId': new FormControl(dataItem.bookId),
  'bookName': new FormControl(dataItem.bookName, Validators.required),
  'pages': new FormControl(dataItem.pages),
  'publisher': new FormControl(dataItem.publisher),
  'genre': new FormControl(dataItem.genre, Validators.required),
  'authors': new FormArray(dataItem.authors)
});
```

Also started checking my values in html

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
  <div *ngIf="!dataItem.authors==null">
    {{log(dataItem.authors)}}
    {{log(formGroup.authors)}}
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let author of dataItem.authors">
        {{log(author)}}
        <strong>{{author.authorName }}</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**But my authors property of dataItem always is null, why is this happening?**
Another columns in grid have correct values, not null.

I found good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003242/after-submitting-edit-form-getting-null-value-when-i-am-checking-console), but this example isn't working with data from remote server.

**UPD2:**

The main problem is here, my dataItem(controls) don't know how to read my array of authors from gridData. How should I change it?(dataItem is the same as book)

```
  'authors': new FormArray(dataItem.authors)
```

Comment: *I didn't find any information how to work with collection in reactive forms*: here it goes, in the official documentation about reactive forms: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups. But it seems you want to *display* information, so why would you need a form? A form is used to *enter* and *submit* information.

Comment: I'm using kendo grid for Angular, and there kendo use reactive forms to edit data in grid. I shortened code for brevity, my template is a part of my  grid column.

Comment: The question is still relevant